# Optimal bandwidth for discontinuity regression with Bernoulli

Tags: regression-discontinuity

I'm trying to run a discontinuity regression to explain a binary outcome. The problem is I do not know how to get the optimal bandwidth.
I've tried to use the `rd.categorical` package by Xu (2017), but the function is fit just to categorical variables that assume more than two values, that is, it is not runnable for binary outcomes.

Please, somebody could help me?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Please review our [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This site is not about getting help with specific statistical package. If you're interested in [tag:regression-discontinuity], please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There are many R packages that can do bernoulli/binomial discontinuity regression out of the box (they are identical for binary outcomes). [See an overview here](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html).

The R package `mcp` with `mcp(model, data, family = bernoulli())`. [See more here](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/binomial.html).